# perlファイルからpostgresqlに接続して結果を知りたい

Tags: postgresql, perl

perlファイルpgをuse(インクルードみたいなの？)してpg::connectdbをしているんですが、そのSQLの返り値を確認したいと思っています

```
#beginをかけます。

$conn = Pg::connectdb("host=$host port=$port dbname=$dbname user=$user");
$result = $conn->exec("lock table table_name in access exclusive mode nowait;");

#commitかrollbackします。
```

で、`$result`にデータが入ると思うんですけど、クエリ結果が問題なければ、`$result->resultStatus;`に値が入ったりますが、そもそもどこがsqlのエラーかどうかの判断をすればいいのか理解できていません。

どこを見るのが正確なんでしょうか？？

Comment: [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~mergl/pgsql_perl5-1.9.0/Pg.pm#2._Result)を見れば分かるのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

質問はPerlというより libpg のお話だと思いますので、既にご紹介されている perldoc に加えて libpgのドキュメントを読まれるのをお勧めしておきます。Perldocの日本語訳がよければ[こちら](http://perldoc.jp/docs/modules/pgsql_perl5-1.9.0/Pg.pod#pod2.32-32080-26524)もあります。

> どこを見るのが正確なんでしょうか？？

クエリ実行結果は `$result->resultStatus` の値で判定します。
値は 次の定数のいずれかです。

- PGRES_EMPTY_QUERY
- PGRES_COMMAND_OK
- PGRES_TUPLES_OK
- PGRES_COPY_OUT
- PGRES_COPY_IN
- PGRES_BAD_RESPONSE
- PGRES_NONFATAL_ERROR
- PGRES_FATAL_ERROR

これらの定数の意味は libpg の[ドキュメント](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/7.3/programmer/libpq-exec.html)に書かれています。